# How to calculate the survival function in R for a glmnet cox family?

Tags: r, glmnet, cox-regression, survival

I have a sample data of 583 type 2 diabetes patients and want to calculate the 5 year incidence probability of an event for every patient. Variables which were collected are time to an event variable censored at 5 years, event status and 38 independent parameters.

Cox regression was giving non significant results for all the variables so elastic net regression specified for a cox family was applied.

The following commands in R were used:

```
library(survival)
library(glmnet)

y<-Surv(time,status)
x<- cbind(Age,Sex,Tobacco,Alcohol,Energy,HbA1c...)
y<-Surv(time,status)

fit<-glmnet(x,y,family="cox",alpha=0.5)

coef(fit)
```

After obtaining the beta coefficients, the risk score (RS) is determined from RS = B1*X1 + B2*X2 + ... + Bn*Xn. Next, I want to calculate the 5 year probability of the event. [Molnar et al. (2017)](https://journals.lww.com/transplantjournal/fulltext/2017/06000/Predictive_Score_for_Posttransplantation_Outcomes.33.aspx) used the formula "1 - S(5)EXP[RS]" and [Yang et al. (2007)](http://care.diabetesjournals.org/content/30/1/65.long) used the formula "1 - S(5)EXP[RS - mean of RS]".

My questions are:

1) How to calculate the survival function S(t) after applying glmnet? Is survfit command an option? Yang et al. states that S(t) is the survival function over t years when the risk score takes the value of its mean. How can this be determined?

2) Which formula is the better choice to use? I can't find any background on the formula developed by Yang et al.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is substantially a duplicate/cross-posted question from stats.SE: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401965/how-to-calculate-the-survival-function-in-r-for-a-glmnet-cox-family

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a methods question and had a duplicate on the CrossValidated.com SE forum.